# Translate transform and RigidBody2d Addforce relative to world space

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I'm developing a game with my friends from University. Currently, I'm in the process of creating a basic movement system for the main player with a box form as its mesh. I used transform.Translate to move the player object left and right and a rigidbody.addForce to allow the player to jump

However, I found out that if the player was rotated due to it falling for a bit, it seems that the script moves the player object relative to the gameObject's axis. I would like to move the player relative to the world and not relative to the player. It would be nice if someone could tell me how to change from local to world. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class PlayerMovement2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private float upForce;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;

    //usahakan semua value di set di dalam script
    //initialize semua value di start, karena start udh memastikan value di set sekian (kalo di global, bisa aja value nya ganti sendiri)

    private bool left = false;
    private bool right = false;
    private bool jumpUp = false;
    private bool sprints = false;

    bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 10;
        upForce = 40000f;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.gravityScale = 6;
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        left = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
        right = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
        jumpUp = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        //sprints = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(left) transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if(right) transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (jumpUp && isGrounded) jump();


    }

    private void jump()
    {
        Debug.Log("jump()");
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * upForce * Time.deltaTime);
        isGrounded = false;
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (!isGrounded) isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way: It's usually not a good idea to use both `rigidbody.AddForce` and `transform.Translate` on the same game object. Either use one way or the other for moving the object, but combining them can lead to unexpected physics behavior.

Comment: I once created a little demo game which helps to better understand how the different ways of moving a game object work: https://philipptheprogrammer.itch.io/unity-tutorial-how-to-move-your-player

Answer (score 1):

As DMGregory pointed out, you can make transform.Translate ignore the rotation of the object by passing `Space.World` as the second parameter:

```
transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

However, you generally should not manipulate the transform of an object directly when that object also has a non-static and non-kinematic Rigidbody. When you have an object which is influenced by physics, then you should only manipulate it through its Rigidbody component. If you manipulate its transform directly without going through the rigidbody then you can encounter a lot of weird physics glitches like phantom forces or imprecise collision detection.

The most direct conversion from your current architecture to using rigidbody-only movement would be to use [`rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3 newPosition)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) instead of Translate. But it might be even better if you can find a way to use rigidbody.AddForce for both jumping and walking.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a question about how the Unity API works, [please take thirty seconds to consult the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html):

> `public void Translate(Vector3 translation);`
>   `public void Translate(Vector3 translation, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);`
>
> **Description**
>
> Moves the transform in the direction and distance of translation.
>
> If `relativeTo` is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied relative to the transform's local axes. (the x, y and z axes shown when selecting the object inside the Scene View.) **If `relativeTo` is `Space.World` the movement is applied relative to the world coordinate system.**

[`AddForce` is already applied in world space](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html):

> **Rigidbody.AddForce**
>
> `public void AddForce(Vector3 force, ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force);`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `force`   Force vector *in world coordinates.*

Comment: Thank you for your and @Phillipp 's reply. It explains a lot to me. I should also mention that I have a habit of seeking a professional when I'm confused as I'm still not used to reading the manual. I'm still quite new to game development and am still trying to get used to the environment.